# Issue linking JS and CSS files on a server - Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iis

Slick slider is not displaying while running on server, but no issue when I'm running it from localhost. Calling the slider on index.aspx but linking in MasterPage. What's the issue?

[Live Demo Here](http://stuiis.cms.gre.ac.uk/ya204/scs/)

Layout:

[image: layout]

[image: stuiis][image: localhost]

```
<!-- Slick Slider -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../inc/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../inc/slick/slick.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using relative links that are correct from the master and not from the page you're including it on. When the two are combined, the links on the Master page will be running in the context of your content page (the index.aspx in this case). I'm assuming this is a normal webforms app? The reason it works locally is probably that it is hosted at the root locally, but in a subfolder when it's on your server. So the `../` relative path makes no difference locally as it can't navigate any further up the directory tree, but on your server it will take it to the directory above where it is hosted in - making the rest of the path wrong by a directory.

You could use one of the virtual root supporting methods with `"~/inc/slick/slick.min.js"`. This link details some of the specifics in the Server Controls section [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116(v=vs.140).aspx). To use this method it's easiest if your script tag is accessible to the codebehind of your master page.

Or if you know where the app will be hosted, use absolute paths (if the app was hosted in the root of the website) `"/inc/slick/slick.min.js"`

Or use the relative path from where the content pages are that use the master, if all of the aspx pages that will use the master are in the same place. `"inc/slick/slick.min.js"`

Comment: Leading from your answer, I checked my images (view in browser) and the main folder was missing in the link **scs**:

public_html
`..scs
..>index.aspx
..>images
..>css
..>inc`

In the end I ended up moving the code from masterpage to index for linking and `images/image.jpg` and `src="inc/slick/slick.min.js"`

However, it still goes funny when I do the same from masterpage.

Thanks for your time buddy.